# RAML formParameters not making it to post method signature

Tags: raml

When my raml definition specified that the post method to my service was expecting json, the generated post method correctly took an object encapsulating that json and conforming to my schema.

However, not that I have changed the post method to accept application/x-www-form-encoded formParameters, the generated post method does not contain arguments corresponding to each parameter. Am I wrong to have expected it to?

Before and working:

```
post:
  description: blah
  body:
  application/json:
    schema: myschema
    example: !include myexample_request_json.json
```

This generated a post method with signature:

```
public Response post(final Myrequest myrequest)
```

But having changed the RAML to:

```
post:
  description: blah
  body:
    application/x-www-form-urlencoded:
      formParameters:
        myparam1:
          description: aaa
          required: true
          type: string
```

I would have expected the generated post method to be:

```
public Response post(final String myparam1)
```

but instead it is:

```
public Response post()
```

Could someone explain why please?

Thank you,

Paul

Comment: What are you using to generate your methods?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you missed the letter `e` when you were writing `formParameters`. Notice that you have `formParamters`.

I advise you to check API Designer as a tool for editing RAML files.

**EDIT**

So, it seems that it is not a spelling error. Unfortunately, I cannot explain why it generates this way, but I can advise you how to achieve that it will generate you

```
public Response post(final String myparam1)
```

So, instead of using `formParameters` and specific type of the content you could go with `queryParameters`:

```
  post:
    description: blah        
    queryParameters:    
      myparam1:
        description: aaa
        required: true
        type: string
```

Comment: Sorry - the spelling is correct in the actual RAML. It was my post that was wrong (now corrected).

Comment: Ok, I edited my answer, have a look if this helps or share your answer if you resolved the issue.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This turned out to be a bug in the maven plugin that was generating the code. Resolving that bug resolved the issue.